# std::function and function type deduced by "using" don't have same type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, std-function, type-deduction

Here is a small example to show the difference of two function types that are not the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using BinaryOperator = T(const T&, const T&);

int main() {

    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << std::is_same<
                      std::function<int(const int&, const int&)>, 
                      BinaryOperator<int>
                 >::value 
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints `false` which is confusing to me. Both types seems to be equivalent. How are they different?

Comment: `std::function` is a template class with overloaded `operator ()`, it is not a function

Comment: You would have the same with `template <typename T>
using BinaryOperator = std::function<T(const T&, const T&)>;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both types seems to be equivalent. How are they different?

Well... no: they are different types.

If you look at the [`std::function`'s page in cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), you can see that `std::function` is a class with partial specialization (only the specialization is defined) declared as follows

```
template <class>
class function; // undefined

template <class R, class... Args>
class function<R(Args...)>;
```

So your `BynaryOperator<int>` isn't equivalent to `std::function<int(const int&, const int&)>` but is equivalent to its template argument.

You can see that is `true`

```
std::is_same<std::function<int(const int&, const int&)>, 
             std::function<BinaryOperator<int>>
>::value //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...................^
```